# Make field value static in access vba

Tags: vba

Hello I am trying to add various values based on Select Case to the value of field. The problem I face is that each time when I get different Case in select statement, the value of the field rather changing adds the value on top.

```
Private Sub ProductID_AfterUpdate()

Dim qflPrice As Variant
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim sqlQry As String
Dim instID As Integer

instID = Me.Form!ProductID.Value
sqlQry = "SELECT Products.Price FROM Products WHERE Products.ProductID = " & instID & ""
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sqlQry)
Me.flPrice.Value = rs!Price

End Sub
Private Sub ExtrasID_Change()
Dim extrID As Integer
Dim addNum As Integer
Static floorPrice As Integer
Static sumPrice As Integer

extrID = Me.ExtrasID.Value
floorPrice = Me.flPrice.Value

Select Case extrID

    Case Is = 1
        addNum = 5
        sumPrice = floorPrice + addNum
    Case Is = 2
        addNum = 10
        sumPrice = floorPrice + addNum
    Case Is = 3
        addNum = 15
        sumPrice = floorPrice + addNum
End Select

Me.flPrice.Value = sumPrice

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Me.flPrice.Value = Me.flPrice.Value + qflPrice is the culprit
```

Replace by: `Me.flPrice.Value = qflPrice`

By the way, you should clean up your code a bit

```
Private Sub ExtrasID_Change()

Dim extrID As Integer
Static qflPrice As Integer
Static numPrice As Integer

extrID = Me.ExtrasID.Value
numPrice = Me.flPrice.Value

Select Case extrID
    Case Is = 1
        qflPrice = 5
    Case Is = 2
        qflPrice = 10
    Case Is = 3
        qflPrice = 15
End Select

Msgbox qflPrice
Me.flPrice.Value = qflPrice
End Sub
```

(you could even just do `Me.flPrice.Value = Me.ExtrasID.Value * 5` and not use select statement in your case, but I'm guessing this is just an example)

Comment: It doesnt solve my problem please take a look what I am trying to do.

Comment: Just settle on a question and stop changing it. And clarify things, this is confusing. Seems like changing sumPrice = floorPrice + addNum to sumPrice = addNum...

Comment: you look at this from different angle I have a price of the floor that come from the table with list of price. That price then is getting saved in orders table. If I do not select any of the extras the price remains the same, with extras depending on what kind of extra added it changes to £5 than to £10 than to £15, the problem is that if in case somebody chooses different option for extras it will be adding same value to floor price value each time on change of the option, I need to keep the value of the floor same and only ad the number relevant to final price.

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed the issue myself by declaring the global variable.

```
Option Compare Database
Public rsqryPrice As Integer
Option Explicit
Private Sub ProductID_AfterUpdate()

    Dim qflPrice As Variant
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim sqlQry As String
    Dim instID As Integer

    instID = Me.Form!ProductID.Value
    sqlQry = "SELECT Products.Price FROM Products WHERE Products.ProductID = " & instID & ""
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sqlQry)
    Me.flPrice.Value = rs!Price
    rsqryPrice = rs!Price

End Sub
Private Sub ExtrasID_Change()
    Dim extrID As Integer
    Static floorPrice As Integer
    Static sumPrice As Integer
    Static numPrice As Integer

    extrID = Me.ExtrasID.Value

    floorPrice = Me.flPrice.Value
    numPrice = rsqryPrice

    Select Case extrID

        Case Is = 1
           Me.flPrice.Value = numPrice + 5

        Case Is = 2
           Me.flPrice.Value = numPrice + 10

        Case Is = 3
           Me.flPrice.Value = numPrice + 15

    End Select
End Sub
```